# Oracle sql query to GROUP BY, ORDER BY and delete the oldest records per ID

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

I want to write an oracle sql query to keep first three latest records ordered by TIMESTAMP and delete the rest for each MACHINE_ID.
I want to know how efficient i can do that. Hope you understand my question!!

Below is the table for example. All the records with USERFILE = 0 can be filtered out in the sql query.

[image]

**Result after - group by MACHINE_ID and sort by TIMESTAMP desc **

[image]

**After leaving the first 3 latest records per MACHINE_ID and deleting the oldest records, final result should be**

[image]

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output in text format. Also show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is:

```
delete from t
    where t.timestamp not in (select t2.timestamp
                              from t t2
                              where t2.machine_id = t.machine_id 
                              order by t2.timestamp desc
                              fetch first 3 rows only
                             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(machine_id, timestamp desc)`.

Comment: It worked but what would be the performance if we try it in large datasets?

Comment: @JMBA . . . With the specified index (that I just added in), the performance should be okay -- comparable with other methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
This is my final query that am going to use.
ID from the query is a primary key, so i think performance wise it will be fine

select M1.ID from MatrisFiles M1 
        where M1.ID NOT IN (select M2.ID from MatrisFiles M2 
        where M2.machine_id = M1.machine_id and userFile = 1 
        order by M2.timestamp desc 
        fetch first :maxFiles rows only)

Answer (score 0):

You can number the rows per machine and then delete all rows with a number greater than 3. Ideally we could simply delete from a query, but I'm getting ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view when trying this in Oracle 19c.

We need two steps hence:

1. find the rows
2. delete the rows

The statement using rowid to acces the rows again quickly:

```
delete from mytable
where rowid in
(
  select rowid
  from 
  (
    select
      rowid,
      row_number() over (partition by machine_id order by timestamp desc) as rn
    from mytable
  )
  where rn > 3
);
```